# rows to columns based on field value

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `docs` and `people`.

- `docs` table contain: `id` and `doc_id`
- `people` table contain: `id`, `doc_id`, `type`, `firstname`, `lastname`

What I want to `group_concat` based on the `people.type` and have the `type` in it's own column.

TABLE schema and data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `people` (
    `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `doc_id` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    `type` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    `firstname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    `lastname` varchar(25) NOT NULL
      ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO people (`id`, `doc_id`,`type`,`firstname`,`lastname`) VALUES
('1','ABC001','From','John','Smith'),
('2','ABC001','To','Jonas','Doot'),
('3','ABC001','To','John','Howard'),
('4','ABC002','From','Holland','Jones'),
('5','ABC002','To','Tim','Jones'),
('6','ABC002','To','Julia','Smith');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
    `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `doc_id` varchar(6) NOT NULL
      ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO docs (`id`,`doc_id`) VALUES 
('1', 'ABC001'),
('2', 'ABC002');
```

Here is what I have currently, it works but there are still "duplicate" rows for the same `doc_id`, what I need is to "merge" the rows with same `doc_id` into one.

```
SELECT d.doc_id, 
       p.type, 
       CASE p.type WHEN 'From' 
            THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN p.type = 'From' 
                 THEN CONCAT(p.firstname,' ',p.lastname) END SEPARATOR '; ') END 'From', 
       CASE p.type WHEN 'To' 
            THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN p.type = 'To' 
                 THEN CONCAT(p.firstname,' ',p.lastname) END SEPARATOR '; ') END 'To' 
            FROM docs d 
      INNER JOIN people p ON d.doc_id = p.doc_id 
GROUP BY d.doc_id, p.type
```

My current output is:
[image: Current Output]

What I'm looking for is:

```
doc_id       From             To
ABC001       John Smith       John Howard; Jonas Doot
ABC002       Holland Jones    Tim Jones; Julia Smith
```

SQL fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/096f891/4

Comment: Can you show what the result should look like? I think you should just remove `p.type` from both `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What do you mean by "type in its own column AND in one single row"? Do you want the types in columns or rows?

Comment: Sorry I've edited the post to include current and desired output. type in its own column.

Comment: What's the point of the `type` column if it's always `null`?

Comment: Ah yes, I don't actually need the column returned. Edited once again

Comment: @Barmar I've removed the p.type from both select and group by but the "To" column is populated with null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `p.type` out of the `GROUP BY`, so you don't put each type in its own row.

Also, the `CASE` expressions should be inside the `GROUP_CONCAT`. Aggrgation functions should be at the top level in grouped queries.

```
SELECT 
    d.doc_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CASE p.type WHEN 'From' 
            THEN CONCAT(p.firstname,' ',p.lastname) 
        END
        SEPARATOR '; '
   ) 'From', 
   GROUP_CONCAT(
        CASE p.type WHEN 'To' 
            THEN CONCAT(p.firstname,' ',p.lastname) 
        END 
        SEPARATOR '; ') 'To' 
FROM docs d 
INNER JOIN people p ON d.doc_id = p.doc_id 
GROUP BY d.doc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using this sql[image]

```
select U.doc_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT( U.`From` SEPARATOR '; ' ) 'From',
  GROUP_CONCAT( U.to SEPARATOR '; ' ) 'To' 
    from (
    SELECT
    d.doc_id,
    p.type,
    ( CASE p.type WHEN 'From' THEN GROUP_CONCAT( concat( p.firstname, ' ', p.lastname ) SEPARATOR '; ' ) END ) 'From',
  ( CASE p.type WHEN 'To' THEN GROUP_CONCAT( concat( p.firstname, ' ', p.lastname ) SEPARATOR '; ' ) END ) 'To' 
FROM
    docs d  INNER JOIN people p ON d.doc_id = p.doc_id 
GROUP BY
    d.doc_id,
    p.type)
    U GROUP BY U.doc_id
```